# pgAgent jobs do not run on databases other than default "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgagent

I am having a problem where I can only run pgagent jobs in default postgres database. I have a remote connection to another server and want to run pgagent jobs in a different database. Do I need to create a new user to run this? I feel that the problem derives from user / permission related issues. Thanks